# For Bluetooth-LE devices in UWP (Windows-10), how do I get get a list of complete device names

Tags: uwp, bluetooth, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gap

I feel like I'm missing something here.

I have had great success using Bluetooth-LE devices with my app, until I tried to use devices with names longer than 8 characters.  I use BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher, and get the advertisements -- I only look at the ones with names filled in, and then only the ones with the services I am interested in.  Looking more deeply at the data returned, I see now that these adverts are the ones with data sections of BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataTypes ShortenedLocalName, which is limited to 8 chars by Bluetooth Spec.

But, now I need to support devices that have 12 character names, and I'm not always getting the type CompleteLocalName. And on one I'm not even getting the ShortenedLocalName. These are 3 fairly different devices, and even on my favorite iOS BLE tools (LightBlue & EFR Connect), I get different results: LightBlue seems to always show the long name, but EFR Connect shows on 2 out of 3 (and, EFR Connect is showing the "complete" local name as just 8 chars). On the Windows "add a device", the same 2 show the 12 char name, and the other shows only 8 chars.  (I'm starting to think the one device may be misconfigured.)

UPDATE: just after sending this, I tried something-- doing a "PAIR" of these devices that were not showing all characters in Windows Device enumeration -- after the PAIR, they show all 12 characters, even after UNPAIR.

I have started to look at the Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher() call -- I get "better" info from this (the Complete name for 2 out of 3).

What is the best practice for discovery of bluetooth low-energy devices that have 12 character names?  It seems the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher alone is not perfect for this.  It seems like I should be getting info from Windows about devices, so the enumerate devices makes sense.  Are there other ideas I should be looking at?

Comment: GATT Device Information service  may be used for those devices so after pairing you get the full name.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, appreciate that.  This is discovery for me, so I was hoping not to have to connect to a device unless I knew it was one I wanted.

Comment: Use any raw advertisement tracing tool to see what exactly your device advertises. Sometimes manual parsing may help as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Received` event of the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` object, there is a `BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs` parameter that contains the full local name:

```
private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    string localName = eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName;
}
```

Keep in mind that the the watcher handles advertisements and scan responses the same way, so if the `eventArgs.AdvertisementType == BluetoothLEAdvertisementType.ScanResponse`, then perhaps the local name is not present. It depends on your peripheral.

Comment: thanks, but my issue is when it either doesn't give the Local Name, or only shows the first 8 chars.  But your comment about ScanResponse is interesting.  Gonna have to look into that more.

Comment: @bobwki Your issue may relate to the data that's in the advertisements/scan responses rather than your Windows parsing of the advertisement data. Use a mobile BLE app like LightBlue to confirm what the peripheral is sending.
According to the "Bluetooth Supplement to the Core Specification" there are two formats for the Local Name. Either the <<Shortened Local Name>> or the <<Complete Local Name>>. Perhaps only the shortened name is being sent by the  peripheral